# TypeError: a[Ec] is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-google-maps

Well, i'm using angular-google-maps, always receiving this error message, now i cleaned all my code and just put a simple example from the lib git, still the same error message.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
            <ui-gmap-marker idkey="marker.id" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events"></ui-gmap-marker>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.map = {center: {latitude: 40.1451, longitude: -99.6680 }, zoom: 4 };
    $scope.options = {scrollwheel: false};

$scope.coordsUpdates = 0;
$scope.dynamicMoveCtr = 0;
$scope.marker = {
  id: 1,
  coords: {
    latitude: 40.1451,
    longitude: -99.6680
  },
  options: { draggable: true },
  events: {
    dragend: function (marker, eventName, args) {
      var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
      var lon = marker.getPosition().lng();

      $scope.marker.options = {
        draggable: true,
        labelContent: "lat: " + $scope.marker.coords.latitude + ' ' + 'lon: ' + $scope.marker.coords.longitude,
        labelAnchor: "100 0",
        labelClass: "marker-labels"
      };
    }
  }
};
```

[Console error log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbnP0.png)

Already tried the version from the package.json from the project, etc, and nothing seems to change.

Comment: Do you happen to minify the code?  I don't see any reference to `a` or `Ec`

Comment: I edit my question and put an image, i think this is related to Angular.js lib with angular-google-maps, tried many versions, also putting the idKey in the directive as requested by the lib.

@TbWill4321 thanks for the quickly response, take a look at my image the reference to a[Ec] coming from Angular.js i think.

Comment: Your console error shows there's a problem at line 19 of `main.js`.  Can you put the first 20 lines of `main.js` up for us?

Comment: This main came from google maps, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/10/main.js,

Doing a plnkr right now.

Comment: Thanks your time @TbWill4321, appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Using the npm last version of angular-google-maps, specific 2.2.1, give the error mentioned.

i solved changing from :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.2.1/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
```

to :

```
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
```

My Angular version is v1.4.7.